# Generic BinaryReader

Tags: c#, .net, binary, deserialization

I'm writing binary serialiser/deserialser to convert a number of object types to/from a byte stream.  The objects represent API commands and their associated responses for a device connected by Bluetooth or USB.  I'm using the `BinaryWriter` & `BinaryReader` to write/read to/from the stream.

The serialiser is easy.  The properites to be serialised are tagged with an attribute that specifies the order in which they are to be written to the byte stream.  I iterate through the properties using reflection and overload resolution handles picking the correct `Write(...)` method of the `BinaryWriter`.

The deserialiser is not quite so simple.  Again I can iterate through the properites in the particular response class that I'm expecting to determine the types that need to be read from the stream.  The tricky bit is picking the correct method to call on the `BinaryReader` to read the value I need.  I've thought of two approaches.

1. A big switch statement that calls the correct `ReadXXXX()` method based on the type to be read.
2. Use the name of the type I need to build the name of the method I need in a string, and then invoke the method using relection.

Is there a simpler way I'm not thinking of?  It's just a shame you can't do overload resolution based on the return type you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used option 1 (big switch statement) in a binary deserializer. A cleaner method could be something like:

```
{
    object result;

    BinaryReader ...;
    foreach (var propertyInfo in ...)
    {
        Func<BinaryReader, object> deserializer;
        if (!supportedTypes.TryGetValue(propertyInfo.PropertyType, out deserializer))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format(
                "Type of property '{0}' isn't supported ({1}).", propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
        }

        var deserialized = deserializer(reader);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(result, deserialized, null);
    }
}

private static Dictionary<Type, Func<BinaryReader, object>> supportedTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Func<BinaryReader, object>>
{
    { typeof(int), br => br.ReadInt32() },
    // etc
};
```

Another option is to let the command classes themselves do the serialization:

```
interface IBinarySerializable
{
    void Serialize(BinaryWriter toStream);
    void Deserialize(BinaryReader fromStream);
}
```

Then in your commands:

```
abstract class Command : IBinarySerializable
{

}

class SomeCommand : Command
{
    public int Arg1 { get; set; }

    public void Serialize(BinaryWriter toStream)
    {
        toStream.Write(Arg1);
    }

    public void Deserialize(BinaryReader fromStream)
    {
        Arg1 = fromStream.ReadInt32();
    }
}
```

And generic serialization methods:

```
void Serialize<T>(T obj) where T : IBinarySerializable
{
    obj.Serialize(_stream);
}

T Deserialize<T>() where T : new(), IBinarySerializable
{
    var result = new T();
    result.Deserialize(_stream);
    return result;
}
```

But this way you might end up duplicating some code. (On the other hand, derived classes can call their parent class versions of Serialize/Deserialize if that makes sense in your scenario, and that works nicely.)

Comment: A couple of really good options, thanks.  I'm leaning towards the first one because it'll fit better with my current code.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I fully understand what you are trying to do. But it very much sound like you shall take a closer look at the BinaryFormatter and its serialization surrogates in .NET. The BinaryFormatter let you easily Serialize and Deserialize objects and the serialization surrogates let you add your custom serialization and deserialization logic and also make it possible to remapp one object to antoher.

Take a look here:

BinaryFormatter
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx

ISerializationSurrogate
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogate.aspx

SurrogateSelector
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.surrogateselector.aspx

SerializationBinder
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder.aspx

You can also see a small example here, where I have a method that can serialize any object to a base64 encoded string, and then a deserialize-method that can deserialize this string. I also add a SerializationBinder to the formatter that remapp the serialization of the type MyOldClass to the type MyNewClass and also add a custom ISerializationSurrogate that can process the values of the fields in the object before it is added to the ner class.

```
public class SerializeDeserializeExample {
   public string Serialize(object objectToSerialize) {
      using(var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
         new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
         return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
      }
   }

   public object Deserialize(string base64String) {
      using(var stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64String))) {
         var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
         var surrogateSelector = new SurrogateSelector();
         formatter.SurrogateSelector = surrogateSelector;
         formatter.Binder = new DeserializationBinder(surrogateSelector);
         return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
      }
   }
}


public class MyDeserializationBinder : SerializationBinder {
   private readonly SurrogateSelector surrogateSelector;

   public MyDeserializationBinder(SurrogateSelector surrogateSelector) {
      this.surrogateSelector = surrogateSelector;
   }

   public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName) {
      if(typeName.Equals("MyOldClass", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
         return RemapToType();
      }
      return Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyName));
   }

   private Type RemapToType() {
      var remapToType = typeof(MyNewClass);
      surrogateSelector.AddSurrogate(remapToType,
                              new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All),
                              new MyCustomDeserializationSurrogate());
      return remapToType;
   }
}

public sealed class MyCustomDeserializationSurrogate : ISerializationSurrogate {

   public void GetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   public Object SetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector) {
      var objectType = obj.GetType();
      var fields = GetFields(objectType);
      foreach(var fieldInfo in fields) {
         var fieldValue = info.GetValue(fieldInfo.Name, fieldInfo.FieldType);
         fieldValue = DoSomeProcessing(fieldValue);
         fieldInfo.SetValue(obj, fieldValue);
      }
      return obj;
   }

   private static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetFields(Type objectType) {
      return objectType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                           BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
   }

   private static object DoSomeProcessing(object value){
      //Do some processing with the object
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a good option.  Unfortunately these classes aren't available in .Net for Metro Style apps, which is my target platform.  I probably should have added a tag for that to my question.